# How do I use unused partition in a dual boot environment

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partition, gparted

I have Ubuntu installed as a host with Windows operating system.I have installed Ubuntu on one Windows drive having around 70 GB of space.

While installing Ubuntu I just specified 30 GB of disk space and rest of 40 GB space is not used.

Now for some requirement I wanted to use the remaining space 40GB.
I have installed `gparted` but I can't use it for my needs.

I attached the screen shot of `gparted` here.
[image]
Can anyone help me in reclaiming the unused space?

Comment: In the image you show, you don't have 40GB of unpartitioned space. Could you explain a bit more? Is Ubuntu a guest OS? Why is everything installed on NTFS partitions? Is this a virtual machine or did you install Ubuntu as a Windows program (wubi)?

Comment: I installed Ubuntu as Windows program(wubi) and that time specified only 30 GB of space

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot it from USB bootable Live CD installation pen drive
2. Open terminal
3. sudo apt-get install lvm2
4. add your partition by creating pv, vg and lv
5. create unallocated partition; add it to pv
6. extend lv and add new pv

Comment: Since you have already 4 primary partition you can not create new partition from unallocated space.

Comment: Can I delete one of the partition and merge it with Ubuntu one?

Comment: Yes delete any partition which is not of your use. make sure you are not deleting any boot partition. Then create extended partition and add innumerable logical paritions into it.

Comment: On which disk? If I understand correctly, the OP has installed using wubi which creates a virtual drive on the host disk. What lvm are you talking about? What are pv, vg and lv? Where should he create the "unallocated partition"?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you've installed with Wubi and you want to use more space. Wubi uses a file on the Windows filesystem, not a partition, so a partitioning tool like GParted won't help you.

You can resize the Wubi virtual disk, and this is by far the easiest solution in your situation. See [Resize Wubi disk](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeWubiDisk) in the Ubuntu community documentation. You need to boot from a Linux live CD/USB (it can be Ubuntu, or another live CD such as [SystemRescueCD](http://www.sysresccd.org/) or the [GParted Live CD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php). What you cannot do, as far as I know, is resize from inside the Ubuntu that's running inside Wubi. (This is one of the limitations of Wubi — it would be possible from a direct-to-disk installation.)

From the external Linux, run these commands as root (start a root shell with `sudo -s` or `su` if needed):

```
mkdir /media/windows
mount /dev/sda3 /media/windows
fsck -f /media/windows/ubuntu/disks/root.disk
resize2fs /media/windows/ubuntu/disks/root.disk 69G
# Assuming there was no error…
reboot
```

Adjust `/dev/sda3` to e.g. `/dev/sdb3` if necessary: if you boot from a USB stick, your hard disk may get a different letter (the digit is the partition number and remains the same). Adjust the path `/ubuntu/disks/root.disk` from the default if necessary.

Comment: Thanks Gilles for your answer.I will get the Live CD by burning the Ubuntu ISO to blank CD but I am not need to be followed next?Also,what Do you mean by "From From the external Linux, run these commands as root".I didn't get it.

Comment: @Ram In the live CD, you need to open a terminal, run the command `sudo -s`, then run the other commands. “Run as root” means that the command requires administrative privileges, using `sudo` takes care of that.

Answer (score 0):

@terdon

hi

PV, VG and LV is in Logical Volume Manager (LVM) context

PV : Physical Volume
VG : Volume Group
LV : Logical Volume

any new partition of linux LVM (8e) type can be added to PV which is added to VG and then added to LV. Now this LV can be managed to extend. Thus more space can be allotted for use by mounting the lv.